# Error while hitting DNS via Amazon Route53 to the given hosts

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

**SETUP**

R53--->ELB(Classic+SSL)--->Nginx(just one instance)

I have a application running on my Nginx server which is listening on port 80. The Nginx instance is working fine and i can hit it via its public IP.

I have now placed a ELB in front of my Nginx , ELB registers my instance as healthy and i can hit ELB(classic) public URL to reach my website. I am terminating SSL on ELB itself

Now when i place a CNAME entry on Route53 ,and point this to my ELB i reach

503 Service Unavailable : No server is available to handle this request.

I tried a lot of things but not sure why this happens.

My Nginx file looks like :

```
server {
        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /home/ubuntu/partner/public;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        # Make site accessible from http://asw.xyz.community/

        #server_name drone.xyz.community;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

        #return 301 $schema://www.drone.xyz.community$request_uri;



        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the [server_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) directive to nginx config. Also see [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

> Server names are defined using the server_name directive and determine
>   which server block is used for a given request. See also “How nginx
>   processes a request”. They may be defined using exact names, wildcard
>   names, or regular expressions:

```
    server_name <Your Route53 Domain Name>;
```

Comment: do `aws elb describe-instance-health --load-balancer-name <elb-name>` what do you see in the Description? can you post this output?

Comment: Somehow it gives me An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the DescribeInstanceHealth operation: LoadBalancer name cannot be longer than 32 characters , though i see healthy instance behind ELB

Comment: just mention the name, not the full DNS

Comment: An error occurred (LoadBalancerNotFound) when calling the DescribeInstanceHealth operation: There is no ACTIVE Load Balancer named

Comment: wait , i see 10.0.1.54 - - [21/Mar/2018:07:18:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1104 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"
10.0.1.68 - - [21/Mar/2018:07:18:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1104 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"

Comment: but i don't get response back from  aws elb describe-instance-health --load-balancer-name

Comment: you said `i can hit ELB(classic) public URL to reach my website` but when I tried to reach `superb-prod-endpoint-2041949029.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com` it shows 503 error, can you check if you have used the correct ELB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167235/discussion-between-nishant-singh-and-sudharsan-sivasankaran).